# Is it possible to use array_walk() to append terms to an array of posts?

Tags: custom-post-types, php, functions, get-posts, terms

I'm creating a masonry post grid of animals.  I plan to filter the the visible posts by toggling classes.  The classes would in turn would be the post's.

I'm using an MVC theme and would like to get all my data within the Controller, and not have to do multiple queries within the theme loop.

I'm thinking something this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

use Sober\Controller\Controller;

class PageOurAnimals extends Controller
{
    protected $acf = true;

    public function animals() {
        $args = [
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'post_type' => 'portfolio',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'order_by' => 'date',
            'order' => 'DESC',
        ];

        return array_map(function($post) {
            $post->terms = [];

           // Maps terms to posts (doesn't work)
            array_map(function($term) {
                if (isset($term)) {
                    array_push($post->terms, $term->slug);
                }
            }, wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'category'));

        }, get_posts($args));
    }
}
```

.

```
 {-- Blade Template --}
    @foreach($animals as $i => $animal)
            <div class="cell {{ implode(' ', $animal->terms }}">
                <div class="animal animated rollin">
                    <figure class="zoom zoom__container animal__figure">
                        {!!
                            get_the_post_thumbnail($animal->ID, 'medium', [
                                'title' => $animal->post_title,
                                'class' => 'zoom__image'
                            ])
                        !!}
                        <div class="animal__overlay"></div>
                    </figure>
                    <div class="animal__caption">
                        <span class="animal__name">
                            {{ $animal->post_title }}
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        @endforeach
```

**Edit**: I looked up the documentation and found array_map doesn't modify the original array, and what I actually want is `array_walk()`.

I've updated the the code to what is below, but it is still returning an empty array.

```
    $posts = get_posts($args);
    array_walk($posts, function(&$post, $index) {
        $terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'category');

        if (isset($terms)) {
            $post->terms = [];

            array_walk($terms, function(&$term, $term_index) {
                // die(print_r($term));
                if (isset($term->slug)) {
                    array_push($post->terms, $term->slug);
                }
            });
        }
    });

    return $posts;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have a problem with variable scopes in here.

```
        array_walk($terms, function(&$term, $term_index) {
            // die(print_r($term));
            if (isset($term->slug)) {
                array_push($post->terms, $term->slug);
            }
        });
```

In this part of your code, you use anonymous function and inside of it you use `$post` variable. But it is a different variable than the one from few lines back - you're in different function now.

But you can simplify that code a lot:

```
$posts = get_posts($args);
array_walk($posts, function(&$post, $index) {
    $terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'category');

    if ( ! empty($terms) && ! is_wp_error($terms) ) {
        $post->terms = [];

        foreach ($terms as $term) {
            $post->terms[] = $term->slug;
        }
    }
});

return $posts;
```

And even easier, if you know some "magic" WP functions like [`wp_list_pluck`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pluck)

```
$posts = get_posts($args);
array_walk($posts, function(&$post, $index) {
    $terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'category');
    $post->terms = []; // Prevents error on blade template's implode()

    if ( ! empty($terms) && ! is_wp_error($terms) ) {
        $post->terms = wp_list_pluck( $terms, 'slug' );
    }
});

return $posts;
```

PS. You have some errors in your $args too.

```
    $args = [
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'portfolio',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'order_by' => 'date',
        'order' => 'DESC',
    ];
```

It should be `orderby` instead of `oder_by`.

Comment: Ah, I've never actually used a callback in PHP, my brain just processed it as a regular condition :p. I appreciate the wp_list_pluck(), definitely gotta remember that.   Thanks for the typo catch, though I think you made one yourself with 'oder_by' haha.

Comment: Hahaha. Yeah, I definitely did :p But you’ve got the point - that’s the important part :)